# send array via jQuery to Ajax-enabled WCF

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-ajax

my js code:

```
var a = ["asdfa", "asdfa", "aaa"];
var data = [];
for (var i in a) data.push({ name: 'keys', value: a[i] });
$.post('<%=ResolveUrl("~/svc/aja.svc/GetMultiple") %>', $.param(data), function(d) {
//do stuff
});
```

my ajax enabled wcf

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Aja
{
    [WebInvoke(Method="POST")]
    [OperationContract]
    public IEnumerable<IdContent> GetMultiple(string[] keys)
    {
        return keys.Select(o => new IdContent { Id = o, Content = o + o });
    }
```

I tried debugging and the Method `GetMultiple` doesn't get hit,(I get error 500)

if I do this by sending a simple string not array, than it works

this the message that I get as a result in firebug :

> {"ExceptionDetail":{"HelpLink":null,"InnerException":null,"Message":"The
>   incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected
>   message formats for the operation are 'Xml'; 'Json'. This can be
>   because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding.
>   See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more
>   details.","StackTrace":"   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)","Type":"System.InvalidOperationException"},"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","Message":"The
>   incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected
>   message formats for the operation are 'Xml'; 'Json'. This can be
>   because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding.
>   See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more
>   details.","StackTrace":"   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)"}

Comment: is the service on the same domain

Comment: @3nigma yes, any other method that has normal parameters like string/ int works

Comment: I've edit my answer, hope some helps~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're having: $.post sends data encoded in application/x-www-form-urlencoded, and this format is not supported natively by WCF. That's the issue.

Now for solutions: as often is the case with WCF, there are quite a few things you can do:

**1)** Change the client side to send some format which the service can understand. WCF understands JSON, so you can use a JSON stringifier (i.e., JSON.stringify from [json2.js from Crockford's implementation](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)). With this, you'd need to change the code to use $.ajax instead of the "shortcut" $.post:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/svc/aja.svc/GetMultiple") %>',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ keys: a }),
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

**2)** "Teach" WCF how to understand the native format for the $.params (or $.post) calls. There are two ways to do that:

**2.1)** Do it "by hand". It's not very trivial, but it can be done. You'll need an `IDispatchMessageFormatter` which can convert from the forms/encoded into the `string[]` parameter for your operation. You'd then need a behavior to hook this new format up and either a new service host factory (to hook the behavior via code) or a behavior config extension (if you want to do it in config). The following links are for posts explaining in more details the [message formatters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx), the [endpoint behaviors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/05/wcf-extensibility-iendpointbehavior.aspx), the [service host factory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/14/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory.aspx) and the [behavior config extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/28/wcf-extensibility-behavior-configuration-extensions.aspx). The code below shows one possible implementation for a dispatch formatter which knows how to deal with string arrays.

```
public class AjaServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return new AjaServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
    }

    public class AjaServiceHost : ServiceHost
    {
        public AjaServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
            : base(serviceType, baseAddresses) { }

        protected override void OnOpening()
        {
            base.OnOpening();
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint = this.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Aja), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebScriptEnablingBehavior());
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyFormsUrlEncodedAwareBehavior());
        }
    }
}
class MyFormsUrlEncodedAwareBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        foreach (var operation in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
        {
            var dispatchOperation = endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Operations[operation.Name];
            dispatchOperation.Formatter = new MyFormsUrlEncodedAwareFormatter(operation, dispatchOperation.Formatter);
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
}
class MyFormsUrlEncodedAwareFormatter : IDispatchMessageFormatter
{
    private OperationDescription operationDescription;
    private IDispatchMessageFormatter originalFormatter;

    public MyFormsUrlEncodedAwareFormatter(OperationDescription operationDescription, IDispatchMessageFormatter originalFormatter)
    {
        this.operationDescription = operationDescription;
        this.originalFormatter = originalFormatter;
    }

    public void DeserializeRequest(Message message, object[] parameters)
    {
        if (message.Properties.ContainsKey(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name))
        {
            var bodyFormat = (WebBodyFormatMessageProperty)message.Properties[WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name];
            if (bodyFormat.Format == WebContentFormat.Raw)
            {
                if (message.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name))
                {
                    var httpReq = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)message.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
                    if (httpReq.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    {
                        var requestBodyParts = operationDescription.Messages[0].Body.Parts;
                        if (requestBodyParts.Count == 1 && requestBodyParts[0].Type == typeof(string[]))
                        {
                            string body = GetRawMessageBodyAsString(message);
                            NameValueCollection pairs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(body);
                            parameters[0] = pairs.GetValues(requestBodyParts[0].Name);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        this.originalFormatter.DeserializeRequest(message, parameters);
    }

    private string GetRawMessageBodyAsString(Message message)
    {
        XmlDictionaryReader reader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
        reader.ReadStartElement("Binary");
        byte[] bytes = reader.ReadContentAsBase64();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }

    public Message SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, object[] parameters, object result)
    {
        return this.originalFormatter.SerializeReply(messageVersion, parameters, result);
    }
}
```

**2.2**) Use the new "jQuery support for WCF" which is published on http://wcf.codeplex.com. Those are some behaviors / formatters which add support for forms/urlencoded requests. But you'll need to change the operation to receive the data in an untyped way (i.e., as a `JsonArray`), and in the code you'd enumerate the items yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a JSON string using the array you are trying to pass as a parameter to the wcf application. Try the following code

Javascript section,

```
 var list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
 var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ list: list });

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "WebService1.svc/methodName",
  data: jsonText,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
 success: function() { alert("it worked"); },
 failure: function() { alert("Uh oh"); }
```

});

Hope this helps...

Comment: this would mean that at the server side I'm going to get a (string list), and than I have to deserialize it myself

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

You cannot map array of values from URL to parameter.

If you want to pass array use HTTP **POST**.

---

***Edited:***

Demo for you~

use mvc2~

The key to success is [traditional](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

set the `traditional` parameter to `true`

```
$(function(){
    var a = [1, 2];
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<%= ResolveUrl("~/Home/PostArray/") %>",
       data: {orderedIds: a},
       dataType: "json",
       traditional: true,
       success: function(msg){alert(msg)}
    });
})
```

Since jquery 1.4 this parameter exists because the mechanism to serialize objects into query parameters has changed.

and action is~

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostArray(int[] orderedIds)
    {
        return Content(orderedIds.Length.ToString());
    }
```

hope helps~`

Comment: I tried post, $.post and [WebInvoke] instead of [WebGet] and still doesn't work. I've edit my question, switched to post and added more details

Comment: I would very easily do this with MVC, but I can't I have to use ASP.NET web-forms, and ajax enabled wcf

Answer (score 1):

Try keeping your server side code the same and changing your client side code to:

```
$(function(){
    var a = ["asdfa", "asdfa", "aaa"];
var data = [];
for (var i in a) data.push({ name: 'keys', value: a[i] });
    $.ajax({
       url: "echo/json/",
       data: data,
       dataType: "json",
       traditional: true,
       success: function(msg){alert(msg)}
    });
})
```

I think your problem may be that the content type is not specified properly when using the `$.post` method.

Answer (score 0):

You Can also Try this

```
var objSearch = [

        { "Key": "Key_Name1", "Value": "asdfa"},
        { "Key": "Key_Name2", "Value": "asdfa"},
         { "Key": "Key_Name3", "Value": "aaa"},
    ];
```

**Here Key_Name Means that u get in wcf Lke (Key=>"Keyname1", Value=>"asdfa")**

```
$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: svcCertificateUrl + '/Fetch',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({"objSearch": JSON.stringify(objSearch) }),
        success: function (data) {});
```